# ignore mysql tables in backup script

Tags: mysql, shell, command, backup

I am following the guide at [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-mysql-backups-with-automysqlbackup-on-ubuntu-9.10) site and trying to exclude databases with the name `turnkey` in them.

```
find /var/lib/mysql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d'/' -f5 | grep -v ^mysql\$ | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```

this command returns all the database names, how can I remove the turnkey ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you show is a Linux / unix shell command.  If you add another step

```
 grep -v turnkey
```

you will omit any lines with the word "turnkey" in them.

Like so:

```
find /var/lib/mysql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | 
cut -d'/' -f5 | 
grep -v ^mysql\$ |
grep -v turnkey 
tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```

You didn't ask if this is a good idea. I don't think it is, because it relies on a particular ondisk structure for the MySQL server daemon software that is not part of the formal specification of the system.  In other words, it could change.

You could do this:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` 
 WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT LIKE '%turnkey%'
 ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME
```

Comment: I appreciate this because I was going by that tutorial, and didn't even consider thinking outside their tutorial, shame on me for not doing it with `mysql -e "...."`, wow thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little improved script without any additional utilities, just pure find:

```
find /var/lib/mysql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! \( -name turnkey -or -name mysql \) -printf "%f "
```

Or just modify your variant to add `turnkey` in `grep -v` statement to exclude it from the list:

```
find /var/lib/mysql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d'/' -f5 | grep -v "^mysql\$\|^turnkey$" | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```